# ExtJS: Div being generated when loading store, produces a css-shadow over the spinner

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have 2 stores, when I execute them I am getting the following DIV being created and I don't understand why. Its directly under the x-body.

It doesn't always happen but once created and every time i refresh a store the spinner on a grid panel is surround by a square with a drop shadow because the display:none is changed to display:block while this spinner is loading.

```
 <div class="x-css-shadow" role="presentation" id="ext-gen1308"
 style="z-index: 29002; right: auto; left: 245px; top: 431px; width:
 189px; height: 189px; box-shadow: rgb(136, 136, 136) 0px 0px 6px;
 display: block;"></div>
```

Does anyone know why its happening ? It has created a id under the html but i don't know where its coming from.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `shadow` of [`LoadMask`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.LoadMask) is set to `'frame'`, you can easily override that and disable the shadow, for example:

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.LoadMask', {
    override: 'Ext.LoadMask',

    floating: {
        shadow: false
    }

});
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1254

Comment: That worked ! Great. Although is there anyway to only affect the grid panel I am using. I am concerned because the fix applies directly to LoadMask that it may affect something else.

Comment: The `Ext.view.Table` has the [`loadMask`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.view.AbstractView-cfg-loadMask) config. If you're using a grid panel you can set this with the [`viewConfig`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-cfg-viewConfig).